# Android Picasso get image bitmap from cache how

Tags: android, picasso

I didn't find any proper example of how to retrieve a bitmap image from cache picasso:

Here is the code where I download an imageview with Picasso.
I need the bitmap image. How to take it from cache?

```
MWGApp.getInjector().getImageLoader().load(url)   
         .placeholder(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.image_coming_soon, context.getTheme()))
                .into(imageVoew);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

From official website you can see that `Picasso` has features like:

- Handling ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.
- Complex image transformations with minimal memory use.
- **Automatic memory and disk caching**. . .

And to get `Bitmap` from `Picasso` you can set your code:

```
Picasso.with(this)
            .load(youUrl)
            .into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

              // here is your bitmap use it
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. In our case, we need to fetch bitmap and apply some transforms and draw it on canvas manually. .get() method did that, but due to a caching limitation (as described in javadoc for method), it kept fetching the image over and over from network. So, .into() does cache the image and return us bitmap. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, String url)
{
    final String CACHE_PATH = context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/picasso-cache/";

    File[] files=new File(CACHE_PATH).listFiles();
    for (File file:files)
    {
        String fname= file.getName();
        if (fname.contains(".") && fname.substring(fname.lastIndexOf(".")).equals(".0"))
        {
            try
            {
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                if (br.readLine().equals(url))
                {
                    String image_path=  CACHE_PATH + fname.replace(".0", ".1");                     
                    if (new File(image_path).exists())
                    {
                        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException|IOException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```